# NodeJs websocket client for Custom Speech Service

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-speech-platform, microsoft-speech-api

I would like to create a websocket client for the Custom Speech service using a programming language such as Java, NodeJs, Go. Where can I find some technical information on how to consume that websocket from scratch (the expected message, fields, etc)?. I already read the CSS documentation but it focuses on how to use the SDK libraries for C#, javaScript, Android. What should I take into account if wanted to create my own SDK for a different language?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Custom Speech Service uses the same API interface as the Bing Speech API, so you can use the Speech Protocol documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/Speech/API-Reference-REST/websocketprotocol.

You can also start with the Websocket Javascript implementation sample at https://github.com/Azure-Samples/SpeechToText-WebSockets-Javascript.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the useful information. After the handshake I try to send a message to the ws but I receive this error: "1002,Missing/Empty header: X-LOBBY-MESSAGE-TYPE" . I did not find any information about that header, do you know what it is about?

Comment: The second link github repository has been archived in 2019. "The version 1.3 of the Cognitive Services Speech SDK is available. The open-source Javascript version can be found at https://github.com/Microsoft/cognitive-services-speech-sdk-js. For other languages and platform check out https://aka.ms/csspeech.

NOTE: This repository is deprecated. Please use the new Cognitive Services Speech SDK!"